# send multiple arrays to backbone collection, render one, save the other

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, backbone.js

I'm building a message board using Backbone and in the collection.fetch() I'm sending two arrays (the posts and the users). Using .parse I'm able to pull the posts array out to render those in a list view, but I'd like to pass along the users array into the view to run a loop where i can match users to posts by the user id.

```
Posts_Controller (Rails)
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @posts = Post.all
    compiled = {users: @users, posts: @posts}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render :json => compiled.to_json}
      format.html
    end
  end


PostCollection (Backbone)
MessageBoard.Collections.PostCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: MessageBoard.Models.Post,
  url: '/posts',
  parse: function(data) {
    var posts = data.posts;
    return posts;
      }
});

MessageBoard.js
MessageBoard.initialize = function() {
  var postCollection = new MessageBoard.Collections.PostCollection();
  var postListView = new MessageBoard.Views.PostListView({
    collection: postCollection,
    el: $('.posts')
  });

  postCollection.fetch();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  MessageBoard.initialize();
});
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you should model your data on the server so that the user info for that post is in the post object

Comment: as another column in the database?

Comment: Your Rails implementation is a bit naive - normally in a relational db you would query a limited amount of posts (not all) and in the post table is a userID column which you perform a JOIN on. The result is that you would end up with a post table with user info for each row.

Comment: something like:
SELECT name FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN posts AS p on u.id = p.user_id

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might consider is keeping a collection of users and a collection of posts at the top level and when parsing the collection of posts you can also set the collection of users. Then in the view fetch from the collection of users the one with the id of the posts author.

```
// assuming
MessageBoard.users = new MessageBoard.Collections.Users();

// you might do something like this
MessageBoard.Collections.PostCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MessageBoard.Models.Post,
  url: '/posts',
  setupUsers: function (usersData) {
    MessageBoard.users.set(usersData, { parse: true });
  },
  parse: function (data) {
    var posts = data.posts;
    if(data.users) {
      this.setupUsers(data.users);
    }
    return posts;
  }
});

// maybe in your Post model
MessageBoard.Models.Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // TODO: memoize
  author: function () {
    return MessageBoard.users.get(this.get('author_id'));
  }
});
```

Comment: i was hoping to avoid having multiple collections but this would be a good solution